# Invalid left-hand side in assignment as Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting Reference error from below code while using code snippet

It saying error near line number 11 ( var request)

I would love to know how can I make it error free

```
function getAddress() {
    var siteUrl = $('#siteUrl').val();

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var county_text = $('#adv_county').val();
    var postal_code = $('#adv_postcode').val();
    county_text = county_text ? county_text + ',' + postal_code : postal_code;
    if (!county_text) {
        return false;
    }
    $('.addressfields').val('');
    var request = {
        address: county_text,
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: 'UK'
        }
    };

}
$('#adv_county,#adv_postcode').change(function () {
    getAddress();
});
function initialize() {
    var adv_county_input = document.getElementById('adv_county');
    var postcode_input = document.getElementById('adv_postcode');
    var options = {
        //types: ['address'],
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: 'uk'
        }
    };
    var autocomplete_county = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(adv_county_input, options);
    var autocomplete_postcode = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(postcode_input, options);
}
```

Thanks for any response

Comment: `No idea about where is the error` --> if the console is telling you the error, it should also give you the line where it occurs.

Comment: and what is the error ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam `invalid left-hand side in assignment`.

Comment: inspect error from the console, and tell us the particular line in your js code. That would be helpful

Comment: @DimagKharab it's in the question `It saying error near line number 11 ( var request)`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney it wasn't mentioned in the original post, it was edited now. my bad

Comment: It works fine so you must have something else going on (I commented out google ref as it's not relevant, or used) https://jsfiddle.net/we0pjfwk/

Comment: Are yuo sure you copied the code correctly? See the **Related** questions for similar errors, and you'll see the kinds of things that cause this. Usually it's a function call to the left of `=`.